# Videogular - cuepoints not updating

Tags: angularjs, html5-video, videogular

I have an application where the cuepoints need to be shown when the event button is clicked. So when i click event1 button a cuepoint should appear at that particular time on the timeline. 
For values that have been hardcoded, the cuepoints are displayed but not when the button is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\default.css" />
        <script src="bower_components\angular\angular.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components\angular-sanitize\angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components\videogular\videogular.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components\videogular-controls\vg-controls.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components\videogular-cuepoints\cuepoints.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components\videogular-overlay-play\vg-overlay-play.js"></script>
        <script src="js\app.js"></script>

        </head>

        <body>[The first arrow shows the hardcoded point and the second is the one generated after clicking on the event1 button. The style is not gettign applied due to which the cuepoint cannot be seen][1]

            <div ng-app="myApp">
                <div ng-controller="HomeCtrl as controller" class="videogular-container">
                    <videogular vg-player-ready="controller.onPlayerReady($API)" vg-theme="controller.config.theme.url">
                        <vg-media vg-src="controller.config.sources"
                                  vg-tracks="controller.config.tracks">
                        </vg-media>

                        <vg-controls vg-autohide="controller.config.plugins.controls.autoHide" vg-autohide-time="controller.config.plugins.controls.autoHideTime">

                            <vg-play-pause-button></vg-play-pause-button>
                            <vg-time-display>{{ currentTime | date: 'mm:ss' :'+0000'}}</vg-time-display>


                            <vg-scrub-bar>
                            <vg-scrub-bar-buffer></vg-scrub-bar-buffer>
                                <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>

                                <vg-scrub-bar-cue-points  class="event1" vg-cue-points="controller.config.plugins.cuepoints.points.event1">
                                </vg-scrub-bar-cue-points>
                                <vg-scrub-bar-cue-points  class="event2" vg-cue-points="controller.config.plugins.cuepoints.points.event2">
                                </vg-scrub-bar-cue-points>
                                <vg-scrub-bar-cue-points  class="event3" vg-cue-points="controller.config.plugins.cuepoints.points.event3">
                                </vg-scrub-bar-cue-points>

                            </vg-scrub-bar>

                            <vg-time-display>{{ timeLeft | date: 'mm:ss' :'+0000' }}</vg-time-display>
                            <vg-time-display>{{ totalTime | date: 'mm:ss' :'+0000'}}</vg-time-display>

                            <vg-volume>
                                <vg-mute-button></vg-mute-button>
                                <vg-volume-bar></vg-volume-bar>
                            </vg-volume>
                            <div class="my-button iconButton" ng-click="controller.addEvent((currentTime/1000),'event1')">EVENT1</div>
                            <div class="my-button iconButton" ng-click="controller.addEvent((currentTime/1000),'event2')">EVENT2</div>
                            <div class="my-button iconButton" ng-click="controller.addEvent((currentTime/1000),'event3')">EVENT3</div>
                            <vg-fullscreen-button></vg-fullscreen-button>
                        </vg-controls>
                    </videogular>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

and the app.js file is as-

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp',
        [
            "ngSanitize",
            "com.2fdevs.videogular",
            "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.controls",
            "uk.ac.soton.ecs.videogular.plugins.cuepoints",
        ]
    )
    .controller('HomeCtrl',
        ["$sce","$scope", function ($sce,$scope) {



            this.onConsoleCuePoint = function onConsoleCuePoint(currentTime, timeLapse, params) {
            var percent = (currentTime - timeLapse.start) * 100 / (timeLapse.end - timeLapse.start);
            this.consoleCuePointsMessages = "time: " + currentTime + " -> (start/end/percent) " + timeLapse.start + "/" + timeLapse.end + "/" + percent + "% = " + params.message + "\n";
            };

            this.config = {
                preload: "none",
                sources: [
                    {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("video/sample_highres.mp4"), type: "video/mp4"}],
                theme: {
                    url: "bower_components/videogular-themes-default/videogular.css"
                },
                plugins: {
                    controls: {
                        autoHide: true,
                        autoHideTime: 5000
                    },
                    cuepoints: {
                        theme: {
                            url:["css/cuepoints.css"
                            ],
                        },
                        points: {
                            event1: [
                                {
                                    timeLapse: {
                                        start: 15
                                    },
                                    onEnter: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                                    onLeave: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                                    onUpdate: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                                    onComplete: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                                    params: {

                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            event2: [
                                {
                                    timeLapse: {
                                        start: 10
                                    },
                                    onEnter: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                                    onLeave: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                                    onUpdate: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                                    onComplete: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                                    params: {

                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            event3: [
                                {
                                    timeLapse: {
                                        start: 50
                                    },
                                    onEnter: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                                    onLeave: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                                    onUpdate: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                                    onComplete: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                                    params: {

                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }               
            };


            this.addEvent = function(num,eventtype){

                var point = {
                            timeLapse: {
                                start: num
                            },

                            onLeave: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                            onUpdate: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                            onComplete: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                            params: {                           
                            }
                }

                if(eventtype=='event1')
                {   
                    var point={
                            timeLapse: {
                                start: num
                            },

                            onLeave: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                            onUpdate: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                            onComplete: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                            params: {

                            }
                    }
                    this.config.plugins.cuepoints.points.event1.push(point);
                }
                else if(eventtype=='event2')
                {   
                    var point={
                            timeLapse: {
                                start: num
                            },

                            onLeave: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                            onUpdate: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                            onComplete: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                            params: {

                            }
                    }
                    this.config.plugins.cuepoints.points.event2.push(point);                    
                }
                else if(eventtype=='event3')
                {   
                    var point={
                            timeLapse: {
                                start: num
                            },

                            onLeave: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                            onUpdate: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                            onComplete: this.onConsoleCuePoint.bind(this),
                            params: {

                            }
                    }
                    this.config.plugins.cuepoints.points.event3.push(point);                    
                }
            };              
        }]
    );
```

Comment: Which Videogular version are you using? List of cue points should update if you change the cue point array as you can see in this demo: http://videogular.com/demo/#/cue-points Also, I don't know if you can have compatibility problems with `uk.ac.soton.ecs.videogular.plugins.cuepoints`. Do you see any console errors?

Comment: I am using the latest version. I installed it using bower. The demo has a static predefined set of cuepoints to be displayed when the "change cuepoints" button is clicked. I want them to be displayed dynamically. Suppose the video is playing and I click the "Event1" button at 10th second, the cuepoint should display at the 10th second on the timeline. No i do not see any console errors.

Comment: I think that it could be a bug or even an unsupported feature, so we will try to add it. Meanwhile, you can try by removing the array and creating a new one with you new cuepoint. That should work as in the demo.

Comment: There's an unfortunate confusion here between [Videogular Cuepoints](https://github.com/HarryCutts/videogular-cuepoints), a plug-in I wrote to display marks on the scrub bar, and [Videogular Cue Points](http://videogular.com/tutorials/videogular-cue-points-synchronize-video-with-twitter/), a later feature for synchronising with outside events. Which one do you want? If you want the plug-in, take a look at [the example project](https://github.com/HarryCutts/videogular-cuepoints-example/). Otherwise, you don't want `uk.ac.soton.ecs.videogular.plugins.cuepoints` in your dependencies.